Visual Studio Code Not Recognizing Flutter Project: No Syntax Highlighting, No Run and Debug Buttons
Image I'm experiencing issues with my Flutter project in Visual Studio Code. The code editor is not providing syntax highlighting, and all the code appears in plain white. Additionally, the typical Run and Debug buttons that appear at the top for Flutter projects are missing. I opened the code again after a week it was working fine at that time.
Here are the steps I've taken to try to resolve the issue:

Reinstalled Visual Studio Code: I completely uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code.

Reinstalled Extensions: I reinstalled the Flutter and Dart extensions.

Checked Environment Variables: I ensured that the paths to my Flutter and Dart SDKs are correctly set in my system's environment variables.

Checked VS Code Settings: I verified that the dart.flutterSdkPath and dart.sdkPath are correctly set in my settings.json file.

Ran flutter doctor: I ran flutter doctor and resolved all issues reported.

Deleted the .vscode Folder in Project: I deleted the .vscode folder in my project directory.

Created a New Flutter Project: I created a new Flutter project to see if the issue persists, and it does.



seems like you are very angry, haha

you are using default theme of VSCode, right? No edit anything? Such as Dracula Theme...

I was using Dracula theme before but not right now!
